# Change the style of a button from one page without affecting the other buttons from other pages

Tags: html, css, button

Any ideas on how i can execute this?

```
button {
    background: #1c00b5;
    width: 100px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(28,0,181,0.3);}
```

i have tried to add "body .contact button" to let css file know it is the contact us page i am editing but it wont work it only goes to change the style on my other pages aswell so essentially.

```
body .contact button {
    background:
```

but this doesnt work, any ideas how i can change the style of this button without affecting the others in my css file?

Comment: Give this button a class?

Answer (score 2):

The `.contact` does not mean the contact page but instead refers to a class called `contact`.

You could give each of the buttons a different class for example if you wanted one to be red and the other blue:

HTML page 1:

```html
<button class="button-red">This is a red button</button
```

HTML page 2:

```html
<button class="button-blue">This is a red button</button
```

CSS file:

```css
.button-red {
    background-color: red;
}

.button-blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Just change the colours to your own styling.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to search online for 'CSS selectors' and learn how and why to use them.

An example: create CSS rules that are true for all `button` and create exceptions to those rules using specific selectors. E.g. all buttons are *green*, except a contact button is *red*.

The *generic* rules can be put in a separate CSS file and `<link>`ed in a document. Create the *specific* rules in-document with a `<style>` block to override/modify/add to the linked generic rules.

There are many alternative ways to solve your issue, this is just one of them...

**Tip:** CSS rules are nothing more than an eleborate list of logical statements varying from easy to virtually unexplicable selectors to modify the style of your document:

```
if selector,
   list-of-selectors,
   very-special-selectors
   what-does-this-one-do?!?-selector then { property: value }
```

**example**

```css
/* put this in an external CSS file */
button         { background-color: green }

/* put this in a <style> block */
button.contact { background-color: red }
```

```html
<button>generic 1</button>
<button>generic 2</button>
<button>generic 3</button>
<br>
<button class="contact">contact</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a button

`<button> your text </button>`

and we ave to use this CSS/style

```
    background: #1c00b5;
    width: 100px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(28,0,181,0.3);
```

so, we will add a id to button like

`<button id="contact-btn"> your text </button>`

and then add style using id selector

```
#contact-btn{
        background: #1c00b5;
        width: 100px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #fff;
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(28,0,181,0.3);
}
```

it will work thanks